# Synchronised Scrolling UICollectionViews in UITableViewCell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have the structure like this:

> UITableView -> UITableViewCell -> UICollectionView ->
>   UICollectionViewCell

So what I’m trying to achieve is that I want to make **UICollectionViews** in **UITableViewCells** to scroll synchronised. For example when you scroll manually the first **UICollectionView** on the first row, I want the rest of **UICollectionViews** to follow, but the Text Labels to stay in the same position all the time. (Please see the image below)

**EDIT**: I know that I have to use `contentOffset` somehow, but don’t know how to implement in this case scenario. Any help would be appreciated.

[**Click to see the image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJXUV.png)

[**Click to see the gif**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waA25.gif)

Comment: I'm sorry but it is no clear what you would like to achieve. could you please post a gif of what you want, or at lest a better explanation?

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza Edited the question with adding the gif. Thanks!

Comment: So if one inner collection view scrolls, all the other must scroll the same. is that correct?

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza That’s totally correct.

Comment: As `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` are subclasses of `UIScrollView`, you can use `UIScrollViewDelegate` to detect the scrolling of a particular `UICollectionView` in `scrollViewDidScroll:` (which could be in a `IBOutletCollection`). After that, you just need to apply the same `contentOffset` to every collection view referenced by your collection.

Comment: Let me try to write some code and I'll come back with an answer if I find a solution.

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollingViewContent/ScrollingViewContent.html), you just need to find a way to detect when the scrolling changes and that's exactly what `scrollViewDidScroll:` does.

Comment: @AlejandroIván what about the cell reusability and memory consumption? Consider at least 20 rows and setting delegates on each of reusable cells.

Comment: @DominikBucher as cells are reusable, you just need to check if the collectionview is not in the array before adding it. Not a big deal, `if ( ! [myArray containsObject:myCollectionView] )`. Also, `IBOutletCollection` should be declared `weak`, since the collection views are retained by the superview.

Comment: @AlejandroIván you are talking about datasource, right? Well I was talking about making the tableView not to lag as hell. Try implement it yourself.

Comment: @DominikBucher I've done it before. 20 rows approximately on screen with an iPhone 5, like a year ago. It doesn't really lag, unless you use a very complex view. On iPhone 5s it performed well. Reusability helps on this matter, of course.

Comment: @AlejandroIván the delegates should be declared weak as well since you could get yourself awesome retain cycle.

Comment: @DominikBucher okay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I managed to get this working, Please keep in mind the code is just for the question purposes and contains lot of non-generic parameters and force casting that should be avoided at any cost.

The class for MainViewController containing the tableView:

```
    protocol TheDelegate: class {
    func didScroll(to position: CGFloat)
}

    class ViewController: UIViewController, TheDelegate {

        func didScroll(to position: CGFloat) {
            for cell in tableView.visibleCells as! [TableViewCell] {
                (cell.collectionView as UIScrollView).contentOffset.x = position
            }
        }

        @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            tableView.dataSource = self
        }
    }

    extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 100
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
            cell.scrollDelegate = self
            return cell
        }
    }
```

The class for your tableViewCell:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    weak var scrollDelegate: TheDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        (collectionView as UIScrollView).delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension TableViewCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "litecoin.png")
        return cell
    }
}

extension TableViewCell: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        scrollDelegate?.didScroll(to: scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    }
}
```

The class for the collectionViewCell is irelevant since it's just implementation detail. I will post this solution to github in a second.

Disclaimer: This works just for visible cells. You need to implement the current scroll state for the cells ready for reuse as well. I will extend the code on github.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a working solution you can test on a playground:

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyCollectionCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
  var originatingChange: Bool = false
  var observationToken: NSKeyValueObservation!
  var offsetSynchroniser: OffsetSynchroniser? {
    didSet {
      guard let offsetSynchroniser = offsetSynchroniser else { return }
      collection.setContentOffset(offsetSynchroniser.currentOffset, animated: false)

      observationToken = offsetSynchroniser.observe(\.currentOffset) { (_, _) in
        guard !self.originatingChange else { return }
        self.collection.setContentOffset(offsetSynchroniser.currentOffset, animated: false)
      }
    }
  }

  lazy var collection: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let collection = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collection.backgroundColor = .white
    collection.dataSource = self
    collection.delegate = self
    collection.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    return collection
  }()

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    collection.frame = contentView.bounds
    contentView.addSubview(collection)
  }

  func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.backgroundColor = .white

    return cell
  }

  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    originatingChange = true
    offsetSynchroniser?.currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    originatingChange = false
  }
}

class OffsetSynchroniser: NSObject {
  @objc dynamic var currentOffset: CGPoint = .zero
}

class MyViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
  var tableView: UITableView!
  let offsetSynchroniser = OffsetSynchroniser()

  override func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)

    tableView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.dataSource = self

    tableView.register(MyCollectionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    self.view = view
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.reloadData()
  }

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.collection.reloadData()
    cell.offsetSynchroniser = offsetSynchroniser
    return cell
  }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

To make it work with a playground you will see a lot of code that if you are using storyboards or xib is not needed. I hope anyway that the base idea is clear.

### Explanation

Basically I created an object called `OffsetSynchroniser` which has an observable property called `currentOffset`. Each cell of the tableView accepts an offsetSynchroniser and on didSet they register with KVO for notifications of currentOffset changes.

Each cells also registers to its own collection's delegate and implements the didScroll delegate method.

When any of those collectionView causes this method to be triggered the currentOffset var of the synchroniser is changed and all the cells that are subscribed through KVO will react to the changes.

The Observable object is very simple:

```
class OffsetSynchroniser: NSObject {
  @objc dynamic var currentOffset: CGPoint = .zero
}
```

then your tableViewCell will have an instance of this object type and on didSet will register with KVO to the var currentOffset:

```
  var originatingChange: Bool = false
  var observationToken: NSKeyValueObservation!
  var offsetSynchroniser: OffsetSynchroniser? {
    didSet {
      guard let offsetSynchroniser = offsetSynchroniser else { return }
      collection.setContentOffset(offsetSynchroniser.currentOffset, animated: false)

      observationToken = offsetSynchroniser.observe(\.currentOffset) { (_, _) in
        guard !self.originatingChange else { return }
        self.collection.setContentOffset(offsetSynchroniser.currentOffset, animated: false)
      }
    }
  }
```

The `originatingChange` variable is to avoid that the collectionView that is actually initiating the offset change will react by causing the offset to be re-set twice.

Finally, always in your TableViewCell, after registering itself as collectionViewDelegate you will implement the method for didScroll

```
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    originatingChange = true
    offsetSynchroniser?.currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    originatingChange = false
  }
```

In here we can change the currentOffset of the synchroniser.

The tableViewController will at this point just have the ownership for the synchroniser

```
 class YourTableViewController: UItableViewController { // or whatever ViewController contains an UITableView
      let offsetSynchroniser = OffsetSynchroniser()
      ...
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionCell
          ...
          cell.offsetSynchroniser = offsetSynchroniser
          return cell
      }
 }
```

Comment: Very good use of keyValueObserving and + for making this a little more generic!

Comment: I edited the answer to explain in detail the solution

Comment: It is working for visible cells only. Please provide if any solution available...

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of off the top of my head to do something like this would be to store all of your collectionViews in a collection object.  You can then use the `UIScrollView`'s `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method from those collectionViews.  Just make sure you have your delegate set correctly.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for view in collectionViewCollection where view.scrollView != scrollView{
        view.scrollView.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    }
}
```

This is untested code, so not a complete answer but it should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!